# Execute Controller Method from razor html view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, html-select

Ok so I have an `Html.DropDownList` and I want to be able to execute a controller method `ActionResult output(string test)` and send a parameter to it. I have something like this already but I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of null message:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"revisions", ViewData["revisions"] as SelectList,
new
{
    onchange = "this.form.action = '/Shops/output('test')'; this.form.submit();"
})
```

How do I go about fixing my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Action method's parameter name is `id`,

```
public ActionResult output(string id)
{
  //do something
}
```

then you may use your form action url like this.(The default routing will take care of rest)

```
/Shops/output/somestringhere.
```

If you have a different name, use that as the query string

```
public ActionResult output(string name)
{
  //do something
}
```

Now use your form action url like

```
/Shops/output?name=somestringhere
```

**Another suggestion** about your code is to avoid Viewdata for rendering the dropdown. Try to use strongly typed view model and it's properties for transfering data to your view. Also try to move your javascript from your view and make it unobutrusive. So that your view stays as clean markup only.

Assuming you want to show a Revision dropdown in a document create view, Add a property to your viewmodel to have the dropdown items.

```
public class DocumentCreateViewModel
{
  //Other properties also here

  public List<SelectListItem> Revisions{ set;get;}
  public int SelectedRevision { set;get;}

  public DocumentCreateViewModel()
  {
    Revisions=new List<SelectListItem>();
  } 
}
```

and in your GET action, fill the dropdown content to the Revisions property.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new DocumentCreateViewModel();
  vm.Revisions=GetRevisionItemsFromSomeWhere(); 

  return View(vm);    
}
```

And in your strongly typed view,

```
@model DocumentCreateViewModel

    @using(Html.Beginform())
    {

      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedRevision,
                     new SelectList(Model.Revisions,"Value","Text"), "Select..")

      <input type="submit" />
    }
```

Now to handle the form submit on change event of dropdown, add this script.

```
$(function(){

  $("#SelectedRevision").change(function(){
     var _this=$(this);
     var selectedRevision=_this.val();     
     $("form#YourFormIDHere")
                .attr("action","./Shops/output/"+selectedRevision).submit();
  });


});
```

Instead of hardcoding the url to shops/output, you may use the razor helper method(`@Url.Action`) to get the proper path.

Comment: Thanks dude, i'm seriously new to MVC, and still a student, but this way of doing things is obviously far better etiquette and programming practice. I'm not sure I understand what's happening in the View when you create the drop down list (the second last segment in your post)?

Comment: @barnacle.m: the DropDownListFor helper method will render a dropdown in the view.  anyway Welcome to the wonderful world of ASP.NET MVC :)

Comment: Haha thank you. That public ActionResult Create(), is that in my controller class?

Comment: Can you explain the parameters you've put there for SelectList()

Comment: Check the official documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"revisions", ViewData["revisions"] as SelectList,
new
{
    onchange = "submitForm();"
})
```

and your Javacript goes here

```
function submitForm()
{
        var form = document.forms[0];
        form = '/Shops/output?test=test'; 
        form.submit();
}
```